# Can CONFIG_NTFS_FS be disabled completely?

Tags: linux, ntfs

I use ntfs-3g as file system type , I'm wondering if `CONFIG_NTFS_FS` is still necessary ? Seem you could remove that.

Also does ntfs-3g have better performance than kernel ntfs driver ?

Comment: If you mean on Linux then you should say so.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes , and edited tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ntfs-3g is `fuse` based, so it should be absolutely ok to disable the kernel module you're asking about. Though, it's still unclear to me why one would want to do that.